In Stripe, does customer.subscription.update fire when they make a payment?
Basically I'm trying to keep the expiration date on a proprietary token matched to the customer's subscription.current_period_end. But I'm under the impression from the docs that customer.subscription.update only fires when they change plans or cancel. Will it not also fire when they make a payment (which I assume would make subscription.current_period_end change?) Sorry, it's difficult to test these month subscription scenarios. If there is another event that would be more appropriate to listen for, I'm all ears.

It should fire for changes to subscription.current_period_end as well. You can test this in Stripe's test mode. Test clocks can help you test things like this quickly.
